# How to show Smart Tags in Winforms Form in Visual Studio 2019

Tags: winforms, devexpress, visual-studio-2019

I've been out of the winforms space for quite a few years.  Trying to find out where the smart tag is in a winforms form in Visual Studio 2019 and how to invoke it.

Following instructions from https://docs.devexpress.com/WindowsForms/402959/controls-and-libraries/ribbon-bars-and-menu/get-started

I cannot, even without devexpress find the windows smart tag. Ideas?

Comment: what do you mean about smart tag? can you provide the related picture to show the smart tags?

Comment: Did you create a .NET Core WinForms project or a .NET Framework WinForms project?

Answer (score 1):

Smart tag is enable by default in design-time. If you don't see it, try:

1. Uninstall Visual Studio.
2. Delete all temporary, settings, data files/folders of Visual Studio.
3. Restart computer.
4. Re-install Visual Studio.